# Google app engine database access on localhost

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am new to Python and Google App Engine. I have installed an existing Python application on localhost, and it is running fine for the static pages. But, when I try to open a page which is fetching data, it is showing an error message:

`BadRequestError: app "dev~sample-app" cannot access app "dev~template-builder"'s data`

`template-builder` is the name of my online application. I think there is some problem with accessing the Google App Engine data on localhost. What should I do to get this to work?

Comment: Consider this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280613/badrequesterror-app-smyapphr-cannot-access-app-devmyapphrs-data-why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are just getting started I assume you don't care much about what is in your local datastore. Therefore, when starting your app, pass the --clear_datastore to dev_appserver.py.

What is happening? As daemonfire300 said, you are having conflicting application IDs here. The app you are trying to run has the ID "sample-app". Your datastore holds data for "template-builder". The easiest way to deal with it is clearing the datastore (as described above).

If you indeed want to keep both data, pass --default_partition=dev~sample-app to dev_appserver.py (or the other way around, depending on which app ID you want to use).