# Admin access error with remote_api handler on AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, remoteapi

Trying to configure my AppEngine app's remote_api, I set up app.yaml with the required:

```
builtins:
    - remote_api: on
```

Then deployed to app engine.  Now, I am system administrator (currently Owner) of this application, but when I access `https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api`, I get the message:

```
`You must be logged in as an administrator to access this.`.
```

Why does this happen?

For completeness, I asked my app's owner and he got the same message. We were both logged in at the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The remote_api URL is not meant to be used from a browser.

Are you using the remote_api_shell.py script?

Comment: Mostly I was trying to debug my development setup as explained in this question I posted: [Remote_api Setup on App Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413826/remote-api-configuration-with-app-engine).  I am getting the error I specify there, and I was checking to see if it had something to do with security privileges.  If you have any pointers regarding that question, I would appreciate it.  If it helps at all, I _have_ managed to connect through the remote_api_shell.py script.

Comment: I think you will just have to read the source.  What you're trying to do is so non-standard that I have no idea how to help you.  Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You must be logged in with and the Google (Gmail?) account that has administrator privileges.

Comment: In my question, I specify I have tried to connect with the "Owner" of the app.  Is there a different sort of admin user?  If so, which?

Comment: It's not clear whether your app has it's own user authentication system or not.  You have to be logged in with the Google login.  Yes, the owner account should work.  From a browser, you should be seeing a different error message.  "This request did not contain a necessary header".  Does the owner account have 2-factor authentication?  That might have something to do with it.

Comment: Thanks! Our application has our own auth system.  I actually believe that has something more to do with it.  I do have 2-factor auth, but I use an application-specific password to access this so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Can you please guid how to login to google in command prompt. I'm getting this error when running command in command prompt.