# devappserver2, remote_api, and --default_partition

Tags: google-app-engine, dev-appserver-2

To access a remote datastore locally using the original dev_appserver I would set --default_partition=s as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280613/badrequesterror-app-smyapphr-cannot-access-app-devmyapphrs-data-why/9281772#9281772)

In March 2013 Google made devappserver2 the default development server, and it does not support --default_partition resulting in the original, dreaded:

```
BadRequestError: app s~appname cannot access app dev~appname's data
```

It appears like the first few requests are served correctly with

```
os.environ["APPLICATION_ID"] == 's~appname'
```

Then a subsequent request results in a call to /_ah/warmup and then

```
os.environ["APPLICATION_ID"] == 'dev~appname'
```

The docs specifically mention related topics but appear geared to dev_appserver [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver)

> Warning! Do not get the App ID from the environment variable. The development server simulates the production App Engine service. One way in which it does this is to prepend a string (dev~) to the APPLICATION_ID environment variable, which is similar to the string prepended in production for applications using the High Replication Datastore. You can modify this behavior with the --default_partition flag, choosing a value of "" to match the master-slave option in production. Google recommends always getting the application ID using the get_application_id() method, and never using the APPLICATION_ID environment variable.

Comment: It's hard coded as 'dev' at google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py, line 84 of ver 1.8.4 SDK.  It worked for me if I change the string.

Comment: Thanks [Kenji Noguchi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/622121/kenji-noguchi) :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following dirty little trick:

```
from google.appengine.datastore.entity_pb import Reference

DEV = os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'].startswith('Development')

def myApp(*args): 
    return os.environ['APPLICATION_ID'].replace("dev~", "s~")

if DEV:
    Reference.app = myApp
```